# Why did my answer to this question get deleted?

Tags: discussion

Why did my answer to this question get deleted? I think I was misunderstood in my intention to clarify the problem and to help with a program I've written myself.

I posted a link to my website and I pay for my website and the traffic but my solution is free.

Question: [HP DV7 shows blank screen and does not start up, probably due to heat issues](https://superuser.com/questions/363011/hp-dv7-shows-blank-screen-and-does-not-start-up-probably-due-to-heat-issues)

Comment: It was converted to comment, not deleted.

Answer (score 6):

Your answer was:

> I'm not exactly in the same boat but maybe I can help. I've a FSC Amilo Xa 3530 also with a Turion X2 Ultra ZM cpu and I can confirm it's getting really hot. After a Windows upgrade the fan controller didn't work properly so I wrote my own. Then I've tweaked the heatsink and removed the bottom case and bought a laptop cooler. When I max out the fan speed with my tool the cpu stills overheat (100 degree) when I stress the box but I make it harder to the cpu to reach the critical temperature when the bios performs a thermal shutdown thus I can use the full potential of my laptop (performance mode). I've wrote linux kernel module as well. Maybe my documentation and my source code can help you to fix your problem. You can find all information on my website: http://www.chihoang.de/code-schnipsel/amilo-xa-3530.html.

Few things:

First

- The answer was not deleted, it was converted to a comment.

Coming to the answer:

- It's an answer which goes oh, I had something related try this - it *may* work, but I can't guarantee
- It's a bare link to your site. If your site goes down, the answer becomes useless
- Following the links to your site, gives me bunch of shell scripts. Not really sure what to do about that,
- There's a program for Windows, but you claim:

  > I'm not a professional Linux or Windows or OS coder at all but most of the time I use Linux, so you can imagine that I've a hard time to learn all this tools in Windows and you need a lot of them to build a kernel driver and a systray application

  Not every confidence inspiring, considering that the program is a Kernel mode driver.

Hence it was converted to a comment.

---

studiohack has also outlined the reasons why it was converted to comment:

> I understand that you're offering your program as a possible solution
>   but the bulk of your 'answer' is a narrative of things you've tried in
>   your own situation, but it is vague and the way it is written, it is
>   not very easy to understand what you mean. **Converted to comment as
>   to allow the post to remain in some form, rather than deleting
>   outright**...
>
> **Perhaps if you would improve your readability and clear up some vague points, I/another mod will consider undeleting**. Explain more
>   about what your script/program could do for the OP, etc and make it
>   clearer what helped and didn't help

Comment: I've a Linux kernel module, a windows kernel mode driver and a windows user space program on my site. There isn't even a single binary to click-and-point and I've wrote exactly how you can solve the problem by changing some bits in the ec? Forgive me if my presentation doesn't please your taste but it's not for you anyway.

Comment: @Jitamaro It's not for me, it's for whoever visits the site. The last thing a user would want to do upon landing on an answer is to be redirected to another site for another needle in a haystack search.

Comment: And about the bare link to my site I've no word for your answer here. Your answer is against superuser rules.

Comment: @Jitamaro ... ? this answer is posted on **meta** Super User, not Super User.

Comment: Where did the user get redirected? If you found ironic speech or english grammar error you can keep that.

Comment: For advertising enquiries, contact the site at the email on the footer @jit

Comment: @random: why should this be advertise?

Comment: The only reason that "answer" was posted was to tell people to look for the answer on your website and nothing else. If that's the whole point, there is no point @jit

Comment: @random: It's wrong I've the same problem like him and I've described away to solve it. IMO i don't understand why a link is advertise!?

Comment: @Jitamaro Your entire answer, if we remove your own problem description, consists of the following: *Maybe my documentation and my source code can help you to fix your problem. You can find all information on my website: [LINK]*. You aren't offering commercial services, but you're advertising your own site anyway without contributing any real content to SU. Despite all those words, it's really a link-only answer to your own site, and these are frowned upon.

Comment: @DanielBeck: That's not exactly true because I wrote some specific information about windows, heatsink, case and laptop cooler. On my site I've documented my code but not really fancy but I have put my code on it.